# Why is this block of code producing runtime error 91

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6, runtime

This block of code is causing runtime error 91 or with block not set error
this code is for opening reports in crystal report in vb6

```
For DocCodeCount = 0 To cboDoctorsCode.ListCount - 1
    strReportTitle = "DOCTOR'S TRANSMITTAL COPY"
    strSqlStatement = "PFMS '" & cboControlCode.Text & "', '" & cboDoctorsCode.List(DocCodeCount) & "', '" & sCurrentUserName & "'"
    strFilename = App.Path & "\Reports\ClaimsBillProc\PF MS.rpt"
    newRpt.OpenReport vADOConnection, strSqlStatement, strFilename, strReportTitle, 3, False
    Set newRpt = Nothing
Next
```

When used in 1 time opening of report it runs fine but when it is used in this manner in the loop it causes error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite clear: You destroy your object within the loop.

This line is the obvious reason for your one time wonder:

```
 Set newRpt = Nothing
```